# Xamarin.Forms How to two-way bind to a control in Listview

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, binding, xamarin.forms

Im having a hard time trying to figure out how to set up a two-way binding for a control inside a listview.

Im using ReactiveUI and Xamarin.Forms.

In this case i would like to load a list of objects that have a quantity. This is set initially when the page loads. However i would like to be able to change these quantity values in the view when the program is run. I used an Entry for that.

Setting up a two-way Binding for the List itself (done in code behind, the reactive way) is not possible. It will error.

Is there another way to observe changes done to the Text property in the Entry control and reflect them to the according item from the list in my viewmodel?

I've been having trouble finding a solution for this and don't really know how to go about this.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<CustomControls:AutoLoadListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="20,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                            <Label Margin="0,5,0,-5" Style="{StaticResource ViewCellPrimaryLabelStyle}"   x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding itemname}" />
                            <Label Margin="0,-5,0,5" Style="{StaticResource ViewCellSecondaryLabelStyle}" x:Name="barcode" Text="{Binding productcode}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Entry Margin="5,0,5,0" x:Name="quantity" Text="{Binding quantity}">
                             <Entry.BindingContext>
                                 <ViewModel:AankoopEditViewModel />
                             </Entry.BindingContext>
                        </Entry>
                        <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" x:Name="delete"  Source="{Mobile:ImageResource tbin_pos.png}">
                             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                 <TapGestureRecognizer
                                  Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand,Source={x:Reference Name=AankoopEditPage}}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
</CustomControls:AutoLoadListView.ItemTemplate>
```

My Viewmodel:

```
public class AankoopEditViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    private VmPurchase Purchase;

    public AankoopEditViewModel()
    {

        PurchaseList = new ReactiveObservableCollection<AankoopEditListItem>()
        {
            ChangeTrackingEnabled = true
        };


        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.PurchaseID).SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe((x) =>
        {
            this.Purchase = DatabaseHelper.Purchase.LoadSingleById<VmPurchase>(PurchaseID);

            if (Purchase != null)
            {
                this.Title = Purchase.supplier.name;

                using (PurchaseList.SuppressChangeNotifications())
                {
                    foreach (var detail in Purchase.purchasedetails)
                    {                          
                        PurchaseList.Add(new AankoopEditListItem { productcode = detail.item.code, itemname = detail.item.namenl, identifier = detail.key, quantity = detail.quantity.ToString() });

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        try
        {
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.PurchaseList).SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe((x) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The List has changed");
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return;
        }
    }




    private string _purchaseID;

    public string PurchaseID
    {
        get { return _purchaseID; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _purchaseID, value); }
    }

    private ReactiveObservableCollection<AankoopEditListItem> _purchases;

    public ReactiveObservableCollection<AankoopEditListItem> PurchaseList
    {
        get
        {
            return this._purchases;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _purchases, value);
        }
    }
```

My Model :

```
public class AankoopEditListItem : ReactiveObject
{
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public string itemname { get; set; }
    public string productcode { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, when you do this

```
<Entry.BindingContext>
   <ViewModel:AankoopEditViewModel />
</Entry.BindingContext>
```

you create a new instance of your view model for each item and you bind your `Entry` to it. Just remove it and keep the binding as it is (`Text="{Binding quantity}"`) if you want to bind your entry to the row view model

Comment: Im now trying to pass the base object as a resource to the entry. so i can use its identifier to update it.

Comment: no not realy. i found a big workaround for this. It uses the event and uses its sender object to get the parent viewcell. Than i get the properties by id, and from there get the according values. Than invoke the command... so yeah. its quite messy.